# No se muestran imagenes Github pages, no se inicia el sitio

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

soy nuevo usando git hub pages. tengo un proyecto react js, en un repositorio de github. Pude subirlo a git hub pages,pero tengo 2 problemas:

1-no se me muestran las imagenes que tengo en la carpeta public.
2- Tampoco inicia el sitio, para poder comenzar a navegar debo apretar en alguna seccion (cuando lo que necesito es que se inicie mostrando seccion inicio)

que podria estar mal?

```
GIT HUB  https://github.com/Nam3216/serigrafia
GIT HUB PAGES https://nam3216.github.io/serigrafia/
```

En cuanto a que no se inicia ya en el inicio, sino que debo apretar en seccion inicio para comenzar a navegar? algun problema con el ruteo sera?

Comment: En lugar de usar `src="serigrafia2.gif"`, usa `src="serigrafia/serigrafia2.gif"`. Lo probé con developer tools y [funciona perfecto](https://ibb.co/6cCjwBM).

Comment: gracias por la respuesta

Comment: En cuanto a que no se inicia ya en el inicio, sino que debo apretar en seccion inicio para comenzar a navegar? algun problema con el ruteo sera?

Comment: ¿Agregaste a tu `package.json` la línea `"homepage": "https://nam3216.github.io/serigrafia/"`?  No la veo en tu repo. Agrega esa línea y vuelve a hacer el deploy.

Comment: Lo agregue pero no es eso. Por lo que pude investigar es algo del ruteo (ya que si subo una app que no usa routes se redirecciona bien) En la version anterior de react vi que se solucionaba en al app.js:
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* routes */}
</Router>

Pero ahora mismo no funciona

Comment: Para aportar la solucion, lo arregle Sacando BrowserRouter, y poniendo en su lugar <HashRouter> en App.js. El tema es que ahora no se ven las imagenes asi como lo habia arreglado..